# Reverse engineering high tec games' network traffic

Tags: reverse-engineering, network-protocols

so I'm trying to deconstruct the messages passed by server-client interaction in a fairly old Halo game through LAN. I've been conducting tests with Wireshark and large packets. Although I am confused as to which type of data I should be analysing. In a chat message packet that was all a characters, I received this:

```
fe:fe:00:03:3a:00:11:19:39:1a:28:0d:b9:20:9d:7b:b8:59:52:90:e3:3e:93:7b:b8:59:52:90:e3:3e:93:7b:b8:59:52:90:e3:3e:93: [SNIP]
```

And in a message with all but the first 3 letters being 'a', I received this:

```
fe:fe:00:21:64:00:68:8f:02:6d:5f:ab:a7:cb:d0:78:0f:e9:6d:55:89:13:72:7b:b8:59:52:90:e3:3e:93:7b:b8:59:52:90:e3:3e:93: [SNIP]
```

Now, I can see some similarities between the packets at some stages (probably the a's), I've come to the conclusion that this:

```
7b:b8:59:52:90:e3
```

Might be an 'a' character. But have no way of proving it. How can I get the above strange string into a readable character, namely, back to 'a'? Is it possible?

Thanks for reviewing this question!
Protocol is UDP.

Comment: have you tried using a hex to ascii converter?

Comment: Should I just.. Slap that bit of data in there? Even with the colons and such?

Comment: Well I was way off. Turns out that small snippet of data actually means:
{?YR??

Comment: yes, got the same result here.. maybe its encrypted..

Comment: I think so too, thanks for your help though !

Answer (score 0):

You just have to attach ollydbg to the process you are trying to understand, and set breakpoints at WSARecv (or recv) http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx
The next packet you receive will hit your breakpoint, follow the memory ptr to see it in a separate window and step over the call WSARecv. You should see a filled buffer now, set a memory breakpoint at the top of the new arrived data and if you press play you should get to the crypt function, if its crypted. (Its possible, that you have to reverse a bit more to get to that point) I hope its a starting point for you to get into reverse engineering assembly :)

Maybe my tut will help a bit, its for another game but i think it should show some ideas:
http://blog.praty.net/?p=315

Greetz defragger

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the protocol by looking at network dumps is very inefficient. I recommend decompiling pieces of a game using modern tools such as [Hex-Rays Decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) and then combining knowledge of data structures used in networking modules with debugging live app using OllyDbg.